# Bootstrap text field next to other inputs, using whole width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to have a `form`, containing a `checkbox`, a `textfield` and a `button`, with `textfield` taking as much `width` as available.
Is that possible?

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input class='form-control'>
    <button class="btn btn-danger pull-right">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i>
  </button>
</form>
```

Here's a [codepen](http://codepen.io/baqtor/pen/YqZWqB) with my (failed) intent

**EDIT:** Changed my question to **not** require `form-inline` to achieve the same result

Answer (score 1):

You can use `calc()` in `input="text"` and according to [Bootstrap Docs Examples](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline) the `button` would be a sibling of `form-group` and not a child as you have.

Remember that `.form-inline`  **only applies to forms within viewports that are at least 768px wide.** So you need to see full-page of the snippet.

```css
.form-group {
  border: red solid
}
input[type="text"] {
  width: calc(100% - 17px)
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="text" placeholder="textfield">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
    Remove<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i>
  </button>
</form>
```

**UPDATE** (based on your updated question) - that you want the same outcome even for smaller screen - therefore don't require `form-inline`)

I'll say lets keep `form-inline` but make `button` child of `form-group` instead of sibling (as I had earlier in my answer - and as it should be accordingly to [Bootstrap Docs Examples](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline))

```css
.form-group {
  border: red solid
}
#f1 input[type="text"] {
  width: calc(100% - 113px) /* regular button */
}
#f2 input[type="text"] {
  width: calc(100% - 101px) /* small button */
}
#f3 input[type="text"] {
  width: calc(100% - 91px) /* extra small button */
}
#f4 input[type="text"] {
  width: calc(100% - 141px) /* large button */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<form id="f1" class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="text" placeholder="textfield">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
      Remove<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
<form id="f2" class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="text" placeholder="textfield">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">
      Remove<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
<form id="f3" class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="text" placeholder="textfield">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-default">
      Remove<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
<form id="f4" class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="text" placeholder="textfield">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">
      Remove<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I see. I guess I shouldn't use form-inline then, since I also want the same effect for smaller viewports, am I right?

Comment: Well accordingly to Docs yes.

Comment: Thanks, I ddited my question

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="checkbox">
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, that's not exactly what I want to achieve. I edited my answer in case it helps